# Eclipse shows ports are in use while running a web app using tomcat v9 even when i change it

Tags: java, eclipse, port

when I try to run a dynamic webpage project, I face ab error that some other process is already using those port numbers. I restarted the PC but it didn't solve the problem. I've tried changing the port numbers but that doesn't work.
Here are the ports I changed it to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the image attached it shows that port 80805 is busy, already in use

```
netstat -aon | findstr 80805
```

The number that is shown as last column of above result is process ID of program that is using your port.

Suppose that number comes to 13360. Then use the following command to know exact process using your port.

```
tasklist | findstr 13360
```

Comment: any port that i use is already in use. Ive tried multiple port combinations, and ive tried killing the process. the only thing that works is removing the server and reconfiguring it.

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are only 16-bit. Pick ones under 65,535.

Comment: i used port numbers of around 60000. still getting that error.

Comment: Is there firewall software preventing that Java runtime from opening ports?

Comment: i went into my firewall settings and turned on both private and public network access for java platform se binary. didnt work. do you want me to allow it for another app too?